# how to apply group data t.test to multi column in r?

Tags: r

I plan to do t.test for `q1` by group `A&B` in df

```
q1 q2 q3 group
1  0  1  A
0  1  0  B
1  1  1  A
0  1  0  B
```

Then the script is :

```
t.test(subset(df,group==A,select = c("q1")),subset(df,group==B,select = c("q1")),alternative = "two.sided")
```

I made a function for t.test script:

```
x<-function(qnum){t.test(subset(df,group==A,select = c("qnum")),subset(df,group==B,select = c("qnum")),alternative = "two.sided")}
```

Then i think `apply` can give me t.test result for `q1,q2,q3...`

```
y<-select(df,grep("q\\d",colnames(df),perl=TRUE))
apply(y,2,x)
```

but has error:

```
Error in `[.data.frame`(x, r, vars, drop = drop) :
```

how to automatic get the t.test result for multi columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle this better using a formula in `t.test()`. For example, `t.test(q1 ~ group, data = df)`.

Below I'll demonstrate by simulating data, using a formula, then using `lapply()` to run `t.test()` for every column (except `group`):

```
# Create data
set.seed(123)  # This makes sampling replicable
d <- data.frame(
  q1 = rnorm(20),
  q2 = rnorm(20),
  q3 = rnorm(20),
  group = sample(c("A", "B"), size = 20, replace = TRUE)
)

head(d)
#>            q1         q2         q3 group
#> 1 -0.56047565 -1.0678237 -0.6947070     B
#> 2 -0.23017749 -0.2179749 -0.2079173     A
#> 3  1.55870831 -1.0260044 -1.2653964     A
#> 4  0.07050839 -0.7288912  2.1689560     A
#> 5  0.12928774 -0.6250393  1.2079620     A
#> 6  1.71506499 -1.6866933 -1.1231086     B

# Example of using a formula
t.test(d$q1 ~ d$group)
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  d$q1 by d$group
#> t = -0.76262, df = 17.323, p-value = 0.4559
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -1.2294678  0.5759458
#> sample estimates:
#> mean in group A mean in group B 
#>     -0.05443279      0.27232820


# How to apply t.test to every column with lapply()
# - d[,-4] is all data excluding `group` variable
lapply(d[,-4], function(i) t.test(i ~ d$group))
#> $q1
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  i by d$group
#> t = -0.76262, df = 17.323, p-value = 0.4559
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -1.2294678  0.5759458
#> sample estimates:
#> mean in group A mean in group B 
#>     -0.05443279      0.27232820 
#> 
#> 
#> $q2
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  i by d$group
#> t = -1.6467, df = 17.731, p-value = 0.1172
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -1.2881952  0.1568201
#> sample estimates:
#> mean in group A mean in group B 
#>      -0.3906697       0.1750179 
#> 
#> 
#> $q3
#> 
#>  Welch Two Sample t-test
#> 
#> data:  i by d$group
#> t = 0.52889, df = 13.016, p-value = 0.6058
#> alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
#> 95 percent confidence interval:
#>  -0.7569843  1.2478547
#> sample estimates:
#> mean in group A mean in group B 
#>     0.253746354     0.008311147
```

Comment: about the ~,the usage is equal to !, i just hard to understand how it become group in R language grammar.

Comment: @jackson883 In R, `~` and `!` are _not_ equal. `!` stands for negation, while `~` is usually used to define a formula within a function.

Comment: nice answer, I have one more question, assume there is another variable, say 'Day of the Week', and I want to know, for each day of the week, is there any difference of q1,q2,q3 between group A and B. Is this possible? how to do that if so?

Comment: I'd be using tidyverse/dplyr. Here's an example snippet to test with: `library(tidyverse); d %>% group_by(day) %>% summarise_at(vars(q1, q2, q3), funs(list(t.test(. ~ group))))`